# Deepin 15.2 Grub выглядит ужасно

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, dual-boot, deepin

На жестком диске стоит Windows 10 вместе с Deepin 15.2. Проблема во внешнем виде grub'а. Запускает системы нормально, только когда переключаешься между ОСями мерцает и очень туго это все делает. И вообще картинка ужасная. Подскажите, как это исправить? Дело в видеокарте или она здесь не при чем?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, /boot/grub/grub.cfg (или тот файл, который у Вас используется). Например на pastebin.com

Comment: похоже просто картинка не фонтан, современное искусство так сказать, прибить, гдето тут должны быть картинки [Order of Search for GRUB Splash Images](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/grub-splash-image/)

Comment: попробуйте сменить тему оформления. судя по содержимому postinst-скрипта пакета *grub-themes-deepin*, как-то так: `sudo /usr/lib/deepin-daemon/grub2 --setup-theme`.

Comment: Надо понимать, что граб работает в режиме 256 цветов, и не любая офигенная картинка будет хорошо смотреться.